# UISearchController returns section instead of the filtered tableview item

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have implemented a `SearchController` and when I search the food item using the `SearchController`, it returns the whole section.

For example, I will search `Chocolate` using the `SearchController` and it would return and result in the tableView displaying the whole section of `Sweets`, instead of just `Chocolate`, it'll return `Lollipops` as well. What am I doing wrongly here? I am fairly new to swift, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
struct Food {
    let foodTaste: String
    let foodList: [String]
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" {
            filteredFood = food
        } else {
            filteredFood = food.filter { $0.foodList.contains(where: { $0.contains(searchController.searchBar.text!) }) }
            self.tableView.reloadData()  
        }  
    }

    var tableView = UITableView()
    var food = [Food]()
    var filteredFood = [Food]()

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        filteredFood = food
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        let sweets = Food(foodTaste: "Sweet", foodList: ["Chocolate", 
        "Lollipops"])
        let sour = Food(foodTaste: "Sour", foodList: ["Lemon", "Limes"])
        food.append(sweets)
        food.append(sour)
    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return filteredFood.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredFood[section].foodList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredFood[indexPath.section].foodList[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return filteredFood[section].foodTaste
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 4
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bus is in the line

```
        filteredFood = food.filter { $0.foodList.contains(where: { $0.contains(searchController.searchBar.text!) }) }
```

Effectively your `food` and `filteredFood` are a 2-dimensional array. The first dimension is the array itself. The second - inner array `foodList` inside the `Food` object. This code filter only the outer dimension of this data structure. It says that if there is a string that matches search inside the `foodList`, then whole `Food` object should pass the filter. If this is not what you want - you have to create new `Food` objects as well. Probably something like this:

```
        filteredFood = food.filter { $0.foodList.contains(where: { $0.contains(searchController.searchBar.text!) }) }
                           .map  { Food(foodTaste: $0.foodTaste, foodList: $0.foodList.filter( {$0.contains(searchController.searchBar.text!) }) }
```